# Using a prepared statement with auto increment field

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I am trying to do insert to a table whose primary key is set to auto increment using a prepared statement.

The fields in the table are as follows;

id, username, password, email, firstname, last name

My code is such that

```
    String sql = "INSERT INTO Users values (?,?,?,?,?, ?)";
    RegistrationStatus status = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement st = null;
    try {
        conn = source.getConnection();
        st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        st.setString(2, username);
        st.setString(3, password);
        st.setString(4, email);
        st.setString(5, firstname);
        st.setString(6, lastname);
        st.executeUpdate();
```

Where i have read that we should no include the first item as the database will take care of it. This approach for me appears to be failing.

Would it be possible to get some help on how to solve this?

Comment: don't include a ? for the PK id argument. you should have only 5 question marks in your insert sql.

Comment: @NathanHughes you should also specify that the ID column won't be set in the SQL insert statement as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your statement to not include the `id` (or the exact name) column:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Users (username, password, email, firstname, lastname)"
    + " values (?,?,?,?,?)";
//...
st.setString(1, username);
st.setString(2, password);
st.setString(3, email);
st.setString(4, firstname);
st.setString(5, lastname);
//...
```